# Direction about future

Tags: string-theory, soft-question, education

I am finishing high school this year and i want to be a theoretical physicist. My academic result in mathematics is not good throughout last 5 years. But physics is my dream. I want to overcome every obstacles. I think i am not bad at mathematics but the reason behind my bad result was lack of concentration. I am going to take double major. Can any one clarify what is the differences between high school math and college math. I also want to know if i work hard and concentrate then is it possible to publish research paper in junior year? My interests are space-time, string theory and m-theory.  Please someone help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about learning physics not doing physics

Comment: I'm afraid your question is off-top here. If you can get 20 reputation points you can [join the Physics chat and ask there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). You'll find lots of people willing to help.

Comment: There is an easy test for your interest. Work trough Landau/Lifshitz Volume I Mechanics. It's online here: https://archive.org/details/Mechanics_541. If you can master this, at least partially, on your own at your age, you may have a shot at becoming a theoretical physicist. At the very least you will get an idea what the most trivial theoretical physics looks like. It only gets tougher from there... much, much, much tougher.

Comment: @CuriousOne Starting with Landau/Lifshitz at high school level seems to me like a bad idea in order to gauge one's interests and capabilities. As it is not intended to be read at that level, it will be unnessecarily discouraging to most people. As the poster is apparently not satisfied with his own mathematical abilities, it would be a much better start to make up for deficiencies in that area and then make the transition to physics problems at undergraduate level.

Comment: @FredericBrünner: The OP asked about the math at the university level. I gave him something that a working theorist has to know in his sleep. In my personal experience we had approx. three students in my first year (among 150 physics students) who had mastered mechanics on the level of Landau-Lifshitz in high school. None of them managed to become a tenured professor of theoretical physics, as far as I know. The most successful of these careers terminated in an assistant professor position while others left academia. That is a reality that the OP needs to know about.

Comment: @CuriousOne As an example of what one has to expect at the university level, your suggestion is definitely a good one. Establishing a correlation between mastering Landau/Lifshitz at high school level and becoming a successful theoretical physicist is, however, a little bit far-fetched, as there are many factors that come into play. But you are right that reality is though, and that you have to become really good at what you are interested in.

Comment: @FredericBrünner: You are correct, there are late-starters. But then, again, how is that going to help a student who admits to be having trouble with high school math? The good news for him is that he can have a very satisfying physics career without being good at math... just not as a theoretical physicist.

Comment: @CuriousOne If he has trouble with math, he should work on improving his skills: learn the necessary tools and improve his mathematical thinking along the way. Given enough time and effort, he can still become good, even at theoretical physics.

Comment: @FredericBrünner: Which is exactly why I told him to read and understand a first semester standard text in theoretical physics. Like I said, if he manages to work trough that, there is a chance.